# Passing values to KO computed observable within an object

Tags: javascript, object, knockout.js, javascript-objects

Trying to expose values to a KO computed observable within an object within an object using javascript. I'm currently getting "undefined undefined" on the page...

```
    function Employee () {            

        var self = this;

        self.identity = ko.observable({
            employeeTitle: ko.observable(""),
            titles: ko.observableArray(['Mr','Mrs','Ms']),
            givenName: ko.observable(""),
            lastName: ko.observable(""),
            otherNames: ko.observable(""),

            fullName: ko.computed(function(givenName,lastName){
                return givenName + " " + lastName;
            })

        });

           //rest of object
  )};
```

Have tried various options and am getting closer - any ideas out there please?

```
function(givenName(), lastName()) { ... }
```

...yields "unexpected token ("

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the following jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JD7fL/.

The function argument to `ko.computed` does not need to take `givenName` and `firstName` as arguments. You can simply reference the fields you want to use within the computed function. But, because you had `fullName` within an object instead of a constructor function, you couldn't reference those fields. I split `self.identity` into a new `Identity` constructor.

The unexpected token error is a result of a rogue closing paren at the end of `Employee`.

### JavaScript

```
function Employee () {            
    var self = this;

    self.identity = ko.observable(new Identity());
};

function Identity() {
    var self = this;

    self.employeeTitle = ko.observable("");
    self.titles = ko.observableArray(['Mr','Mrs','Ms']);
    self.givenName = ko.observable("John");
    self.lastName = ko.observable("Doe");
    self.otherNames = ko.observable("");

    self.fullName = ko.computed(function(){
        return self.givenName() + " " + self.lastName();
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new Employee());
```

### HTML

```
<div data-bind="with: identity">
    <div data-bind="text: fullName"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Just to show how i'm using it (but still not working in this context) see http://jsfiddle.net/G2cKu/

Comment: Glad I could help! In that case you will need something like a [foreach binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) to iterate through your `employees` array in a parent element of the outermost div in that fiddle. You can ask a new question if you'd like a more detailed answer.